# MYSQL simple question about creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR7L3.png)

Failed Run

Comment: Specify the database in which the table must be created explicitly. I.e. `CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name ( ..`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first define what is your default Schema or Database so that your query will know where it should place the table.

in MYSQL Workspace, Double Clicking the Schema will automatically sets it up as default and ready to go.

Comment: Default database is a setting which is set in server's options file. The client may not have an access to its edition. The client must set **current** schema/database.

Comment: Where does your Database server runs? I suggest if for learning purposes only or experimental. Use Mysql and Mysql Server or XAMPP server. You can set modify it on your own and have more freedom in exploring. Tho its kinda cryptic at first